# UDP receive fails after network adapter disabled and enabled again

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking

I use Windows Sockets (mswsock.DLL) in my c++ Win32 application. This application opens a socket listening for udp multicast messages. Everything works fine, but when I deactivate the network adapter and activate it again, messages are no longer received. In Wireshark  the messages are monitored. After restart the application receives messages again.
Does anyone has an idea, how to detect the network adapter disabling?
Regards
Sven

When I pull off the network cable I get Socket closed. But in case of reactivating the network adapter I get no callback message.

Comment: The Win32 function `NotifyIpInterfaceChange()` can be called to request a callback whenever the state of a local network interface has changed:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-notifyipinterfacechange

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I will test your solution.
But is it right behaviour of the windows socket?
Strange is, that after reactivating the network adapter receiving udp packets fails without any notification or so. But sending works fine. So the socket is not completely broken.
Regards Sven

Comment: I'm not sure what the expected behavior is in that case -- the problem might be something specific to multicast, like perhaps the network switch has IGMP snooping enabled and thinks that the network interface is no longer subscribed to the multicast group and thus isn't routing the packets to you anymore.  You could try re-joining the multicast group afterwards and see if that helps.  (In my code I just close and then recreate all my sockets after a network config change; dunno if that's overkill but it seems to do the trick)

Comment: Thanks again. I will try this. But I also try to contact Microsoft.